# How can I maintain line breaks when I copy text to an input?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I have in JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#test1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var newLine = "%0D%0A";
    
    var emailBodyText = "";
    
    emailBodyText = "This is line 1" + newLine + "This is Line 2" + newLine;
    emailBodyText = emailBodyText + "This is also another line.";
    
    var dummy = $('<input>').val(emailBodyText).appendTo('body').select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    });
});
```

The input that comes up is like this:

[image: Image here]

When I paste, it gives me:

```
This is line 1%0D%0AThis is Line 2%0D%0AThis is also another line.
```

How can I copy it with new lines?

Comment: Try `\n` instead of your 0D0A

Comment: `%0D%0A` is a URL-encoded Carriage Return followed by a Newline character. The normal string equivalent of that is `\r\n` or `\x0D\x0A`. Inserting strings into the DOM does _not_ perform URL decoding.

Comment: @mplungjan I tried replacing the `newLine` with `var newLine = "\n";`, and it just gave me: `This is line 1This is Line 2This is also another line.`. Maybe the input does not support multiple lines?

Comment: An `<input>` can only contain one line. You need to use a `<textarea>`  for your line breaks to be kept

Comment: Seems you are looking for a text editor like tinyMCE or [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable)

Answer (score 1):

An `<input>` cannot contain new lines. Use a `<textarea>` instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var newLine = "\n";
    
    var emailBodyText = "";
    
    emailBodyText = "This is line 1" + newLine + "This is Line 2" + newLine;
    emailBodyText = emailBodyText + "This is also another line.";
    
    var dummy = $('<textarea>').val(emailBodyText).appendTo('body').select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test1">test1</button>
```

Comment: Cool! Can I also add HTML/CSS code, to make the first line green color and bold?